# Exclude Certain Recipients in Distribution List

Tags: outlook, active-directory

I have a unique problem. We have a Distribution List with our team members in IT on it. Every morning, we send out an email to the DL. But a specific set of people don't want to receive this email. is there a way to still have them on the DL but not receive a specific email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no trivial way for setting that out of the box. You can retrieve the distribution list programmatically, extract the required recipients from it and send an email to them added to the BCC field.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)

Use the [DistListItem.GetMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.distlistitem.getmember) method which returns a [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object representing a member in a distribution list. The following VBA sample code shows how to deal with distribution lists and their members:

```
Sub DisplayYourDLNames()
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myDistList As Outlook.DistListItem 
 Dim myFolderItems As Outlook.Items 
 Dim x As Integer 
 Dim y As Integer 
 Dim iCount As Integer 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
 Set myFolderItems = myFolder.Items 
 iCount = myFolderItems.Count 
 For x = 1 To iCount 
   If TypeName(myFolderItems.Item(x)) = "DistListItem" Then 
     Set myDistList = myFolderItems.Item(x) 
     For y = 1 To myDistList.MemberCount 
       If myDistList.GetMember(y).Name = myNameSpace.CurrentUser.Name Then 
         MsgBox "Your are a member of " & myDistList.DLName 
       End If 
     Next y 
   End If 
  Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I will consider this option